# mass deploy Oracle patches with OEM with different OS's

Tags: oracle

I have not been able to get this to work. We are running our OEM grid control database/oms on Red Hat 5(32 bit), but our databases are on Solaris x86-64. I could not mass deploy agents since the Operating Systems were different.

When I download patches it is by OS. Is there a way to mass deploy to multiple operating systems? I have alot of databases. I was given the redhat server for OEM because it was available.

We are have 10.1,10.2, and 11.1 databases. OEM DB is 10.2.0.5

Answer (score 0):

When you're talking about multiple OS's for software distribution you're really talking a pricey solution. [Tivoli Configuration Manager](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/tivoli/products/config-mgr/) can handle what you are doing. It can push to Linux, Solaris, HP-US, AIX, and Windows.

Just a warning, though. It's pricey pricey pricey. And the software costs aren't the only part of it - it requires dedicated hardware and most likely dedicated personnel to run it. However, if you have many distributions (patches, applications, etc.) that you regularly push out to multiple OS's, I've yet to see a better solution than TCM. (BTW - I do mean TCM, not IBM's current iteration TPM (Tivoli Provisioning Manager). Stay away from TPM.

Here are some links to Tivoli services companies:

- [Gulf Breeze Software](http://www1.gulfsoft.com/)
- [NewGen Technologies](http://newgentechnologies.com/)

~ Shawn Anderson